# Why does the `useSyncExternalStore` example call `getSnapshot` 6 times on store update?

Tags: reactjs

I added a log statement to the `getSnapshot` function. When clicking `Add Todo`, it is called 6 times. This seems excessive.

Reproduction here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-shadow-4z4nfr

Original example here: https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore#subscribing-to-an-external-store

Answer (score 3):

First, the `<StrictMode>` element deliberately causes a double render in a dev build, so that's responsible for 3 of the 6 calls. The remaining 3 calls are:

1. React checks if rendering is needed. As part of this it calls getSnapshot to get the old data. ([source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1943))
2. The render then happens, and it calls getSnapshot for use during that render ([source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1812))
3. Because this is a dev build, it makes a duplicate call to get the state so it can give a warning if you havn't implemented caching properly ([source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L1815))

If this was a prod build then strict mode would have no effect and #3 would be skipped. So in prod there are 2 calls to getSnapshot: one to see if a render is necessary, and one during that render.